# Way to adjust to DRY principle

Tags: java, dry

I have web-scraping app that simply scrapes books from two big bookstores. The idea is user put type of category in URL e.g `/romances` , `/biographies` .

The **controller**:

```
package bookstore.scraper.controller;

imports...

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class BookController {

    private final MostPreciseBookService mostPreciseBookService;
    private final CategorizedBookService categorizedBookService;
    private final BestSellersService bestSellersService;

    @Autowired
    public BookController(MostPreciseBookService bookOperationsService, CategorizedBookService categorizedBookService, BestSellersService bestSellersService) {
        this.mostPreciseBookService = bookOperationsService;
        this.categorizedBookService = categorizedBookService;
        this.bestSellersService = bestSellersService;
    }
    
.....


    @GetMapping("/romances")
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15RomanticBooks() {
        return categorizedBookService.get15BooksFromRomanceCategory();
    }

    @GetMapping("/biographies")
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BiographiesBooks() {
        return categorizedBookService.get15BooksFromBiographiesCategory();
    }

    @GetMapping("/guides")
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15GuidesBooks() {
        return categorizedBookService.get15BooksFromGuidesCategory();
    }

    @GetMapping("/fantasy")
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15FantasyBooks() {
        return categorizedBookService.get15BooksFromFantasyCategory();
    }

    @GetMapping("/crime")
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15CrimeBooks() {
        return categorizedBookService.get15BooksFromCrimeCategory();
    }
}
```

And the **service**:

```
package bookstore.scraper.book.scrapingtypes;

import bookstore.scraper.Bookstore;
import bookstore.scraper.book.Book;
import bookstore.scraper.empik.EmpikFetchingBookService;
import bookstore.scraper.merlin.MerlinFetchingBookService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static bookstore.scraper.JSoupConnector.connect;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class CategorizedBookService {

    private final EmpikFetchingBookService empikBookService;
    private final MerlinFetchingBookService merlinFetchingBookService;

    @Value("${external.library.url.empik.romances}")
    private String romancesCategoryEmpikURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.empik.biographies}")
    private String biographiesCategoryEmpikURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.empik.crime}")
    private String crimeCategoryEmpikURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.empik.guides}")
    private String guidesCategoryEmpikURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.empik.fantasy}")
    private String fantasyCategoryEmpikURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.merlin.romances}")
    private String romancesCategoryMerlinURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.merlin.biographies}")
    private String biographiesCategoryMerlinURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.merlin.crime}")
    private String crimeCategoryMerlinURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.merlin.guides}")
    private String guidesCategoryMerlinURL;

    @Value("${external.library.url.merlin.fantasy}")
    private String fantasyCategoryMerlinURL;

    @Autowired
    public CategorizedBookService(EmpikFetchingBookService empikBookService, MerlinFetchingBookService merlinFetchingBookService) {
        this.empikBookService = empikBookService;
        this.merlinFetchingBookService = merlinFetchingBookService;
    }


    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromRomanceCategory() {
        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks = new HashMap<>();

        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, empikBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(romancesCategoryEmpikURL)));
        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.MERLIN, merlinFetchingBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(romancesCategoryMerlinURL)));

        return bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks;
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromFantasyCategory() {
        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks = new HashMap<>();

        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, empikBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(fantasyCategoryEmpikURL)));
        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.MERLIN, merlinFetchingBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(fantasyCategoryMerlinURL)));

        return bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks;
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromCrimeCategory() {
        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks = new HashMap<>();

        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, empikBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(crimeCategoryEmpikURL)));
        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.MERLIN, merlinFetchingBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(crimeCategoryMerlinURL)));

        return bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks;
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromGuidesCategory() {
        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks = new HashMap<>();

        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, empikBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(guidesCategoryEmpikURL)));
        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.MERLIN, merlinFetchingBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(guidesCategoryMerlinURL)));

        return bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks;
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromBiographiesCategory() {
        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks = new HashMap<>();

        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, empikBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(biographiesCategoryEmpikURL)));
        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.MERLIN, merlinFetchingBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(biographiesCategoryMerlinURL)));

        return bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks;
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a lot of the same code. I have made something like this, but do not know wheter it is well done:

```
public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromCategory(String merlinCategoryURL, String empikCategoryURL) {
 

   Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks = new HashMap<>();

bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, empikBookService
        .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(empikCategoryURL)));
bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.MERLIN, merlinFetchingBookService
        .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(merlinCategoryURL)));

return bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks;
}
```

I was thinking also about creating one method in controller like:

```
@GetMapping("/{category}")
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15CategorizedBooks(@PathVariable String category) {
        ...
    }
```

but it is hard for me to create universal method in Service.

The question in the end. Is it good way to have that many `@Value` annotations in Service?/ (using yml files to store URL's).

Comment: I think this should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is best suited on Code Review SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question in the end. Is it good way to have that many @Value
>   annotations in Service?/ (using yml files to store URL's).

It is not because you inject too fine grained properties. These should be encapsulated into a specific object : more readable, maintainable and testable.

Spring provides `@ConfigurationProperties` to do that.
It has to annotate the class that contains the properties.
You can do it in this way :

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("external.library.url")
public class BookStoreUrlProperties {

    private Empik empik = new Empik();
    private Merlin merlin = new Merlin();    
    // getters/setters    

    public BookStoreUrlProperties() {
    }

    public static class Empik {

        private String romances;
        private String biographies;
        private String crime;
        private String guides;
        private String fantasy;        
        // getters/setters    
    }

    public static class Merlin {

        private String romances;
        private String biographies;
        private String crime;
        private String guides;
        private String fantasy;    
        // getters/setters    
    }

}
```

Then inject this bean as any other bean :

```
@Autowired
BookStoreUrlProperties bookStoreUrlProperties;
```

And use the getters to retrieve the url such as :

```
String RomanceUrl = bookStoreUrlProperties.getMerlin().getRomances();
```

Another alternative that I would advise is to split the properties (merlin and empik) in two properties classes.

About the duplication in the service class, you can easily factor out them by a extracting parameter refactoring since the only difference is the URL values.

For example :

```
public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromGuidesCategory() {
   return get15BooksFrom(guidesCategoryEmpikURL, guidesCategoryMerlinURL)
}

public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromBiographiesCategory() {
   return get15BooksFrom(biographiesCategoryEmpikURL, biographiesCategoryMerlinURL)
}

public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFrom(String bookStoreEmpikURL, String bookStoreMerlinURL) {

    bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, empikBookService
            .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(bookStoreEmpikURL)));
    bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.MERLIN, merlinFetchingBookService
            .get15BooksFromCategory(connect(bookStoreMerlinURL)));

    return bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks;
}
```

Comment: "These should be encapsulated into a specific object " - could you give me example where should I have this link (I mean, when fetching them from yml file), in another class? Best for me would be gist in which I can see where to place URL's and how to use them in service class. Thanks in advance. Btw. As I see you placed the same method as I in the question which can help to refactor to adjust to DRY principle. So I think it is good way, right?

Comment: I see that if I use `@ConfigurationProperties ` then i dont have to use `@Value` annotation. As I said, that point is I dont know where should I connect with these URL's from yaml e.g class named bookstoreURLs and make every variable static so that I can use it in my Service?

Comment: I updated with a concrete example. No tested code but it should be very close of a working code.